# For loop to Create lines of raster mosaics in ArcMap 10.5

Tags: arcpy, mosaic

For loop to Create lines of raster mosaics
With the tool clip raster, I am using a for loop code (code included) which works well.

```
>>> import arcpy
>>> in_raster_folder = "D:\KKR\ct_igeoref"
>>> in_polygon_folder = "D:\KKR\ct_plgs"
>>> out_clip_folder = "D:\KKR\ct_iclipped"
>>> arcpy.env.workspace = in_raster_folder
>>> in_rasters_list = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "ALL")
>>> for raster in in_rasters_list:
...     raster_name = raster [:-4]
...     clip_poly = in_polygon_folder+"\\"+raster_name+"_iplg.shp"
...     out_raster = out_clip_folder+"\\"+raster_name+"iclp.img"
...     arcpy.Clip_management(raster,"" , out_raster, clip_poly, "256", "NONE", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
```

Now using the tool MosaicToNewRaster  I need to create 6 lines of mosaics using each time sets o 6 rasters (basic code included).

```
arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(input_rasters="D:/KKR/ct_iclipped/018_cticlp.img;D:/KKR/ct_iclipped/019_cticlp.img;D:/KKR/ct_iclipped/020_cticlp.img;D:/KKR/ct_iclipped/021_cticlp.img;D:/KKR/ct_iclipped/022_cticlp.img;D:/KKR/ct_iclipped/023_cticlp.img", 
    output_location="D:/KKR/ct_moslines", 
    raster_dataset_name_with_extension="ct_line1.img", 
    coordinate_system_for_the_raster="", pixel_type="8_BIT_UNSIGNED", 
    cellsize="", number_of_bands="3", mosaic_method="LAST", 
    mosaic_colormap_mode="FIRST")
```

My mosaic lines are:

```
Line1 with 018_cticlp.img + 019_cticlp.img + 020_cticlp.img + 021_cticlp.img + 022_cticlp.img + 023_cticlp.img
Line2 with 026_cticlp.img + 027_cticlp.img + 028_cticlp.img + 029_cticlp.img + 030_cticlp.img + 031_cticlp.img
Line3 with 034_cticlp.img + 035_cticlp.img + 036_cticlp.img + 037_cticlp.img + 038_cticlp.img + 039_cticlp.img
Line4 with 042_cticlp.img + 043_cticlp.img + 044_cticlp.img + 045_cticlp.img + 046_cticlp.img + 047_cticlp.img
Line5 with 050_cticlp.img + 051_cticlp.img + 052_cticlp.img + 053_cticlp.img + 054_cticlp.img + 055_cticlp.img
Line6 with 058_cticlp.img + 059_cticlp.img + 060_cticlp.img + 061_cticlp.img + 062_cticlp.img + 063_cticlp.img
```

Comment: I don't see an actual question here. What's the issue or where is the problem?

Comment: I appreciate your reply. I need to write the mosaicTonewRaster_management code into a "for loop". Otherwise, I have to write the code for each line one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A loop like this should do what you desire:

```
for x in range(6):
    set_of_images = ';'.join(['D:/KKR/{}_cticlp.img'.format(str((18 + x * 8) + y).zfill(3)) for y in range(6)])
    arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(input_rasters=set_of_images, 
        output_location="D:/KKR/ct_moslines", 
        raster_dataset_name_with_extension="ct_line{}.img".format(x + 1), 
        coordinate_system_for_the_raster="", pixel_type="8_BIT_UNSIGNED", 
        cellsize="", number_of_bands="3", mosaic_method="LAST", 
        mosaic_colormap_mode="FIRST")
```

It will run Mosaic to New Raster 6 times, each time feeding it 6 rasters sequentially numbered starting at 018 (026, 034, etc.), and outputting raster datasets sequentially numbered starting at 1.